# when passing argument to R script via command line string gets split at blank spaces

Tags: r, command-line, jython

I am running an R script via the command line (which is initiated by a Jython script). I want to pass a file location to the R script however if the file location has spaces in it, the string gets split at those spaces to make a list.

I can pass an argument and run the R script in Jython using:

```
cmd = '"C:\\Program Files\\R\\R-3.5.1\\bin\\Rscript"'+" "+'"C:\\filelocation"'+" "+"C:/filelocation" 
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd)
```

In R I then use the following to get the passed argument:

```
args <- commandArgs(trailingOnly = TRUE)
```

The problem I having is that if there is a space in the name of the folder, the string gets split at the spaces. Therefore instead of args being one string for the file location it becomes a list split at every space. I can fix this problem in R using the following (to make the file location one string):

```
location <- paste(args, collapse = " ")
```

is there a better solution to this problem?

thanks for your time,

Mike